# Pass a value dynamically to SQL Server through VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Disclaimer: I am new to VBA.

I hope to pass the value in the SQL query (30881570) through a field on my Excel sheet. I have tried a few different things.

```vb
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

    Call cmdClear_Click

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection, cmd As New ADODB.Command, rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    With conn
        .ConnectionString = _
            "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=PRGTAPPDBSWC019; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=DETEP;" & _
            "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        .Open
    End With

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tbl_PMHeader] WHERE [PMHeader_PM_NUM] = '30881570'"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    Set rs.Source = cmd
    rs.Open

    'Need this to populate header row, starting at specified Range
    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Range("B1").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

    'This is where your data table will be copied to
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:BB").AutoFit

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A25").Formula = "=COUNTA(B:B)-1"

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean you "have to pass the value"? Is this a parameter (a value to be used as query criteria?)  ..because it looks to me like you're already doing that?

Comment: What is happening instead? Are you getting any errors? Have you tried stepping through the code to check variable values (or use `Debug.Print` statements)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already passing that value as criteria for the query's `WHERE` statement.

If you're asking how to replace that with a value from a worksheet, here's one way:

```
.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tbl_PMHeader] " & _
    "WHERE [PMHeader_PM_NUM] = '" & Sheets("mySheet").Range("A1") & "'"
```

...where your worksheet is named `mySheet` and the value is in cell `A1`.

This is the simplest method, potentially fine for internal use by trusted parties, but if the value has any `'` single-quotes in it, you will get an error.

Worst-case scenario, this method leaves you open to **[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)** attacks.  Depends on your needs (and whether this this is just a school assignment), you may be better of using a **parameter query**.

---

### See Also:

- MSDN Blog : [**How and Why to Use Parameterized Queries**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/)
- MSDN Blog : [**Everything About Using Parameters from Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/aa160564.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your way doesn't give me any errors. But do you know why it is not giving me a blank table?

Comment: I meant it gives me a blank table, instead of a 50 something records.

Comment: I suggest parameterized queries rather than building SQL strings.

Comment: @SidneyBookeart perhaps there are no records matching the criteria you've specified, but it's impossible to know for sure without having some idea what you're trying to do and what your data looks like (ie.,are you using the correct data type for your criteria?)

Comment: Hi both,Thank you for all the help. I finally got it to work. Tryingout some error handling now. Cant get it to work. I am trying to present an error to the user when they do not provide an entry. How would I do that. I understand we need and if then statement but where do I place it considering my code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sqlStr As String



    With conn
        .ConnectionString = _
            "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=PRGTAPPDBSWC019; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=DETEP;" & _
            "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        .Open
    End With

    orderno = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A22")
    strSql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tbl_PMHeader] " & _
        "WHERE [PMHeader_PM_NUM] = " & orderno


    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = strSql
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    'Call cmdClear_Click

    Set rs.Source = cmd
    rs.Open

    'Need this to populate header row, starting at specified Range
    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Range("B1").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next

    'This is where your data table will be copied to
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:BB").AutoFit

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A25").Formula = "=COUNTA(B:B)-1"

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I finally got it to work. Tryingout some error handling now. Cant get it to work. I am trying to present an error to the user when they do not provide an entry. How would I do that. I understand we need an if then statement but where do I place it considering my code. Thanks again!